# how to get more tokens acknowledged in my for loop batch script, outputting %%a, etc

Tags: csv, for-loop, batch-file, cmd, token

Here is the code that I am trying to run:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set "input_file=%CD%\file3.csv"
type nul > file4.csv

for /f "tokens=* delims=," %%z in ('type !input_file!') do (
    set line=%%z
    for /f "tokens=1,2,3,4,15,19,20,41,42,43,44,45,55 delims=," %%a in ("!line:,=^,!") do (
    set newline=%%a,%%b,%%c,%%d,%%e,%%f,%%g,%%h,%%i,%%j,%%k,%%l,%%m
    for /f "tokens=* delims=," %%x in ("!newline:^=!") do (
    set nline=%%x
    echo !nline! >> file4.csv
)
)
)

pause
```

It is outputting just straight up

```
,%%h,%%i,%%j,%%k,%%l,%%m
```

in the newline variable after the actual data in 1-20. How do I get the for loop to consider those later tokens?

Comment: From the documentation: `tokens=x,y,m-n` and `The m-n form is a range, specifying the mth through the nth tokens.` So try something like `tokens=1-12*`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for /f "tokens=1,2,3,4,15,19,20,* delims...%%a in (....
 for /f "tokens=19,* delims...%%i in ("%%h") do
  for /f "tokens=1,2,3,4,5,15 delims...%%k in ("%%j") do

  echo %%a,%%b,%%c,%%d,%%e,%%f,%%g,%%k,%%l,%%m,%%n,%%o,%%p
```

should extract the appropriate tokens.

Comment: i had to change the 19 to a 20 but other than that it worked for me thank you magoo.