# Batch Close opened files of all users except one

Tags: batch-file, fileserver

Fileserver 2019.
I want to close all opened files except for one user.

```
for /f "skip=4 tokens=1" %%a in ('net files') do net files %%a /close
```

Now, I tried to exclude a specific user with its files, I see that the user is stored in third token.

```
for /F "skip=4 tokens=3" %%a in ('net files^|findstr /i "Andrew"') do echo %%a
```

But I don't know how to close a file if I'm searching only username token. How to return back to file id?
So I tried with net session:

```
net session \\<ip> /delete
```

But I have several users connected from the same IP address, so I cannot use this.
Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for /F "skip=4 tokens=1,3" %%a in ('net files') do if /i "%%b" neq "Andrew" ECHO net files %%a /close
```

Should show you the files to be closed [theory] if so, remove the `ECHO` keyword to activate.

A representative sample from `net files` would make this question easier to answer, I believe. Not everyone uses a multi-user environment.

Comment: After "Andrew" I added the following code: if /i "%%b" neq "command" because the last string returned is "The command completed succesfully."

Comment: So I can use more than one token per time and the next is stored in %%b and so on, thank you Magoo.

Comment: You certainly can - up to about 20. I've never experimented with the limits, but you'd start running out of metavariables by then - but see https://stackoverflow.com/a/72399655/2128947 and remember that the metavariable is case-sensitive. I'd suspect the token number is likely to peg out at 31, so selecting token 65 is unlikely to produce the expected result. See `for /?` from the prompt for docco - or thousands of articles on SO.